# Deleting rows from Python Dataframe with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to delete some rows from huge dataset in Pandas. I decided to use iterrows() function for searching for indexes to delete (since I know that deleting while iteration is bad idea). 
Right now it looks like that:

```
list_to_delete = []
rows_to_delete = {}
for index, row in train.iterrows():
    if <some conditions>:
        list_to_delete.append(int(index))
        rows_to_delete[int(index)] = row
train = train.drop([train.index[i] for i in list_to_delete])
```

It's giving me such error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/patka/PycharmProjects/PARSER/getStatistics.py", line 115, in <module>
    train = train.drop([train.index[i] for i in list_to_delete])
  File "C:/Users/patka/PycharmProjects/PARSER/getStatistics.py", line 115, in <listcomp>
    train = train.drop([train.index[i] for i in list_to_delete])
  File "C:\Users\patka\PycharmProjects\PARSER\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3958, in __getitem__
    return getitem(key)
IndexError: index 25378 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 25378
```

How is it possible?

Before that I created a copy of this dataset and tried to delete chosen rows from this copy while iterating through original one (with inplace=True). Unfortunately there was error saying that NoneType object has no attribute 'drop'.

I would appreciate your help very much.
My example row looks like that:

```
resolution Done 
priority Major 
created 2000-07-04T13:13:52.000+0200 
status Resolved 
Team XBee 
changelog {'Team" : {'from':...
```

Comment: Not sure what your problem is not seeing the structure of your dataframe, anyway I think it should be `train.drop(list_to_delete)` instead. Cheers.

Comment: @lrzcig your solution is giving me `KeyError: '[10 1000 1001 ... 998 9984 999] not found in axis'`
I've got dataset with approximately 20000 rows, example one looks like that:

`resolution                                                        Done
priority                                                         Major
created                                   2000-07-04T13:13:52.000+0200
status                                                        Resolved
Team                                                           XBee
changelog            {'Team" : {'from':...`

Comment: Hi. Please modify your question instead of using the comments. There's very little space here. You can use the `edit` button below your question. Just a wild guess, are your indexes really integers? Why do you do `list_to_delete.append(int(index))` instead of `list_to_delete.append(index)`.

Comment: @lrnzcig I edited the post. Thank you for solution. I was sure that indexes were int - and they were, earlier when I didn't have orient='index' argument in my from_dict function usage and indexes seemed to be doubled (one indexing was mine in string, second one was done automatically and it was int). Yes, they are nowdefinitely strings. Stupid thing and I tried to figure it out for 2 days. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. For future reference, to make your question useful to others, maybe you could post an answer, and even accept it yourself. Just a suggestion. Cheers.